# Undefined index in deleting $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, count, session-variables, unset

I have this code to delete any idea from a cart... I need to delete two`$_SESSION`. 
1) **$_SESSION["cart_array"]**

2 **$_SESSION["minicart"]**

Without me adding `$_SESSION["minicart"]`  it  does delete the `$_SESSION["cart_array"]` but when i added it i got the `minicart` part i got an `undefined index: minicart`. So I

**tried**

**if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && !isset($_SESSION["minicart"]) || count($_SESSION["minicart"]) < 1) {**

*the code above checks // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty**

to the *orginal* **if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {**

So

```
<?php

 //   if user wants to remove an item from cart
 if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"] ["$key_to_remove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]);
    }
}
?>
```

**My quesion**
Looking at the **tried** what I am i doing wrong in the `if` statement and also what am I doing wrong in the `statement` to delete the `($_SESSION["cart_array"]) AND ($_SESSION["minicart"])`

If this is still unclear please leave a comment and I will do my best to explain it again.

Comment: just test for the existance of the key prior to trying to unset it. `if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1)`

Comment: @Orangepill i still got `undefined index:minicart` in line 73 where `if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1) {` is

Comment: It should be `if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1)`

Comment: That's where you must ask `isset()` first. Otherwise you will access a nonexistant index with the count function.

Comment: You could better use the `empty`-function. If you use `count` on an empty array/string, it will return the `undefined index` error.

Comment: @Orangepill i still got undefined index:minicart in line 73 where if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1) {

Comment: If you use the isset first then the second half of the statement will not be run because of logical short circuiting. If the left hand side of a && expression results in false php knows that the whole expression will be false regardless of the outcome of the right hand side so the right hand side is never evaluated.

Comment: @Pieter i used empty and they error is gone BUT now the code to delete the item which is the code to `//   if user wants to remove an item from cart` is not working :'(

Comment: @amy this error was addressed on the third comment.

Comment: @Orangepill i dont understand what u mean

Comment: Your code should read `if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1)` to avoid that error

Comment: do u want me to post the full code to my page? it about 213 lines including the htmls

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {`

to

`if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && ($_POST['index_to_remove'])) {`

or `!empty` instead of `isset`

Comment: i did this but its not deleting the item anymore

Comment: Try for `!empty` instead of isset

Comment: i need t use `isset` seems am posting something from a `form` when the delete button has been press

Comment: First of all why you are adding isset for `$_POST['index_to_remove']` twice? And are you posting the form parameters properly?

Comment: `blo` yes I am... the php code i did does `// Access the array and run code to remove that array index`

Comment: Have you tried with just `if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) {` rather than `if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && ($_POST['index_to_remove'])) {`

Comment: i try it and it 50% works... the problem is that it doesn't delete the `['minicart']` session and 2) when i refresh the page i get a `underfined index:minicart`

Comment: Try `if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && (!empty($_SESSION["minicart"]))) {`

Comment: still getting the same error on `if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1) {`

Comment: I change the `count` to `!empty` and i dont get the error but `['minicart']` session haven't been deleted

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && (!empty($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]))) {`

Comment: okay the cart it is not showing any error. I have check if the both the `cart_array` and `minicart` session are empty using `if(isset($_SESSION['minicart']['cart_array']) && !empty($_SESSION['minicart']['cart_array'])) {
   echo ("I am not empty");
    }`
although the cart looks clear. The `cart_array` and `minicart` sessions is not deleted

Comment: How about `session_destroy()` rather than unset?

Comment: `session_destroy($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]);` not working

Comment: I really can't figure out the problem with the code, if there is no need of any session if the statement is true, the just add `session_destroy()`, it will destroy all the session..

Comment: I am echoing `<?php echo count($_SESSION["cart_array"])?>` and `minicart` do you think that why it is still showing?

Comment: yes thats why unset will be suitable because I am only removing the session variable that is getting posted

Comment: Just a final shot, try `if (exist($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && ($_SESSION["cart_array"] <= 1)) { 
  unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]); 
}` and in else statement remove space between mini_cart and `$key_to_remove` and also put `$key_to_remove` as `'$key_to_remove'`

Comment: No, basically replace the second if and else part as `if (exist($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && ($_SESSION["cart_array"] <= 1)) { 
  unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]); 
} else {
  unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]['$key_to_remove']); 
  sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}`

Comment: still nothing... do u want me to post my full code on this question? maybe i did something wrong that i cant find

Comment: u r not in the discussion room

Comment: @bio The problem has been fixed

Comment: just realised I haven't fix it. If I have more than 1 item in the cart `cart_array` only shows `1`. It should count all the items in the arrays and because of this if I delete 1 item from the cart it deleted everything

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) 
    && !isset($_SESSION["minicart"]) || count($_SESSION["minicart"]) < 1) {
```

You have a boolean logic problem here.  This is not preventing $_SESSION['minicart'], or $_SESSION['cart_array'] for that matter, from being accessed if it is not set.  That accessing when not set is what is giving you your error.  Check your negations (!), and whether you really want || there.

I don't understand what all you need to check before unsetting those $_SESSION values, I don't have enough information and context.  As such, I can't give you code to copy in paste into yours.  All I can do is tell you why you're getting undefined index errors.  Your if statement, which is supposed to keep $_SESSION['cart_array'] and $_SESSION['minicart'] from being accessed if they aren't set, is not doing what you intended.  Trace through it and check your logic.  If you can't make it work, then simplify it by breaking that into multiple, nested if statements.

If you want copy and pastable code, you will need to clarify what your doing a bit more.  What are you checking with the count() parts, under what circumstances do you want to unset variables, and which variables do you want to unset.

Comment: u r missing about 3 `)`

Comment: this just completely stop an item getting add to my cart

Comment: Okay, you were focusing on the wrong part of my answer, so I changed it.  Check your if statements, they're not doing what you intend them to do.

Comment: I fixed it my way but dont know if it is the right way by doing this... I deleted all the `['minicart']` from this pages so only session variable  `['cart_array']` left then where i calculated the total price i did `$cartTotal = $minicart = money_format("%n", (double)$cartTotal);` and i put `minicart` in a session ` $_SESSION['smallcart']=$minicart;`